# Ion-footer sticky to ion-content and bottom of screen

Tags: html, css, ionic2

I wanna make ion-footer, which height will depend on content height, like that

[image: how should it works]

Also , footer can't be smaller than on the 2 image (min-height).

Content is dynamically generated (ion-list *ngFor).
This is my current pseudo-code

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>
      Title
    </ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content padding>
  <ion-list>
    <button ion-item *ngFor="let item of items">
      {{ item.name}}
    </button>
  </ion-list>
</ion-content>

<ion-footer class="footer">
</ion-footer>
```

CSS:

```
.footer{
  background-color: blue;
  min-height: 10em;
  height: auto;
}
```

But it's never fill all empty space on the screen, i still have like that:

[image: how it works]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The ion-footer approach will not work here as ion-footer CSS style has absolute positioning. This means its height cannot be relative to ion-content height.

The required layout can be achieved by a different approach using flex.

```
<ion-content >
 <div style=" display: flex;flex-direction: column;height: 100%;">
     <ion-list padding-horizontal padding-top style="overflow-y: scroll;max-height: 90%;">
       <button ion-item *ngFor="let item of items">
       {{ item.name}}
      </button>
     </ion-list>
     <div style="flex: 1;background-color: blue;">Footer</div>
 </div>
</ion-content>
```

Remove ion-footer element from the HTML.
This should give a similar layout.

Comment: Yea, its sth i need, but this footer does not 'touch' to the right/left and bottom of the screen (cus content is padding <- i need it)

Comment: You can remove padding from ion-content and put it in ion-list. This way the footer div element does not get any padding now.

Comment: but it still empty space on the right (prob. of scroll)

also when we have much items (we need to scroll) , this footer is not sticky to bottom, what it should.

Comment: It will not be an issue when app is viewed in mobile as scrollbar will be in overlay mode.

Comment: i edit last comment, but prob. you didn't see it,
also when we have much items (we need to scroll) , this footer is not sticky to bottom, what it should.

Comment: I have made an update in the code. Check if this fixes the issue.

Comment: Yea, that works good. But I have one more problem (maybe not big trouble). When I'm scrolling now, there is a little "empty space" between ion-list and that footer.
[image](http://imgur.com/r1JFlk3)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149558/discussion-between-jay-and-rf-96-rf).

Answer (score 6):

I'd like to propose another approach, "more ionic-way", using its own components instead of a div an a few style rules.

The solution of Jay solves the problem via CSS, putting the sticky footer fixed to the bottom within the content. However, I've moved the  component out of the , so, it will always remain at bottom of the page:

```
<ion-content>
  // Page content
</ion-content>
<ion-footer>
  // Footer content
</ion-footer>
```

To see an online example, I've created an StackBlitz [here](https://ionic-2qz9ue.stackblitz.io). I hope this could be useful for you (although a bit late), and for future readers.

Comment: thanks, my mistake was that I placed `ion-footer` inside the `ion-content` while it should be outside - that solved my problem !

Answer (score -1):

try

```
height:100%;
```

it worked on for me just now.

Footer was extended as the items grew or shrank.

Comment: No, it makes that footer fill full screen (also footer cover content)